# Lilypond: Different vertical space

Tags: lilypond

**Sometimes** (not every time) when a song (because of the lyrics under the score) takes two pages Lilypond adds an extra space between the lines. How to avoid it?

First image regular space:[image]

Second image extra space:[image]

code for lyrics under the score: (usually one with the original language and one with translation)

```
\markup\fill-line
{
   \left-column
   {
   \vspace #2

   \line {original language}
   \line {original language}
   }
}

\markup\fill-line
{
  \left-column
  {
  \vspace #2

  \line {translation}
  \line {translation}
 } }
```

Comment: Your issue is most likely with vertical positioning properties. Try looking into the documentation at [4.4 Vertical spacing](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/vertical-spacing) and [4.1.4 Flexible vertical spacing `\paper` variables](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.22/Documentation/notation/flexible-vertical-spacing-paper-variables) to see if you can change something there.

Comment: Also worth pointing out: your description references space between “the lines” (assuming you mean the systems or staves). The images show that, as well. However, your code block is markup, which you say goes beneath the score. I don’t think that the latter relates to problem of the former.